# Play music from memory in Android

Tags: android, media-player

Is there a way to play a song that exists as an array of bytes in memory and not as a file on disk?

I know I could save it in a file temporarily and play it form there but I'd like to avoid this as I'm trying to implement a DRM system that will not expose unencrypted media files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AudioTrack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). But it supports raw LPCM data only.

Comment: There is no support for easy mp3 playback from memory.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll accept the answer since it kind of answers the question!