# I am trying to play music from SDcard

Tags: android, media-player, kotlin

// I am trying to play music from SDCARD , one after the other but I want to play the second music after the compilation of the first music. It should automatically happen. I am new to android, any help would be appreciated. with the give code. I can play music

```
class Play : AppCompatActivity() {


    var play: ImageView? = null
    var stop: ImageView? = null
    var AudioSavePathInDevice = "Blesson"
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play)

         play = findViewById(R.id.play) as ImageView
         stop = findViewById(R.id.stop) as ImageView

        play!!.setOnClickListener {

            play!!.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            stop!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val file = intent.extras["file"]
            for (hello in 1..3) {

                AudioSavePathInDevice = File("$file/bless$hello.mp3").toString()


            Toast.makeText(this, AudioSavePathInDevice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
                try {
                    mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice)
                    mediaPlayer!!.prepare()

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Recoring not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                mediaPlayer!!.start()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Playing",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener{}

                try {
                    mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                    mediaPlayer!!.release()
                }catch (ex: Exception){ }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play music from memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425778/play-music-from-memory-in-android)

Comment: No, Its a complete different question

Comment: @blessonSamuel can you put up an example project on github?